# Phprunner - Edit menu

Tags: php, html, css

Take a look at the Menu on this page [here](http://xlinesoft.com/livedemo/phprunner/livedemo3/products_list.php)

I would like to remove

> **» Products**

from

> **Orders and Products » Products**

Whenever I navigate to subpages, The path gets included and its very annoying since it makes the menu size long! Kindly help me to get rid of it please!

Comment: Does editing styles or templates solves this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to visual editor on top you can see the menu editor. You can as much as you like if menu and links. And also you can get ride of them